# after_commit not triggering sidekiq job in rails 5

Tags: sidekiq, ruby-on-rails-5

Below line is not triggering the sidekiq job in rails 5 for bootstrap. but after_update is triggering the same job.

> after_update_commit   :set_sprint_workspaces

Please shed some light on this!